# Mangled names in debugger with source maps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, source-maps, grunt-contrib-uglify

The debugger in Chrome/Safari does not show unmangled variable names when using source maps generated with grunt-contrib-uglify. Source code is displayed and debugged correctly. I have verified that the source map contains the variable names. Is this a bug in uglify?

Original source:

```
// two

function two()
{
    var test = "test";

    console.log("this is a " + test);
}
```

Generated source:

```
function two(){var a="test";console.log("this is a "+a)}
//# sourceMappingURL=all.min.js.map
```

Source map:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "all.min.js",
    "sources": ["../src/two.js"],
    "names": ["two","test","console","log"],
    "mappings":";;AAEA,QAASA,OAEL,GAAIC,GAAO,MAEXC,SAAQC,IAAI,aAAeF",
    "sourceRoot":"../"
}
```

Comment: There is issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327092

Comment: I would suggest setting your grunt-contrib-uglify settings to include `{ compress: false, mangle: false }`. Although this increases the size of the minified file it may alleviate the problems you're seeing

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @rd5, this is [issue 327092 in Google Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327092), reported on 2013-12-09.

As of 2018-07-01, the issue is still unresolved.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I have seen this for example with a source map, and the source map contains the full source code https://spectrum.chat/create-react-app/general/sourcemaps-not-working-in-production~2995d466-e080-4d35-8151-bad3e7f8fb98 e.g. the "sourcesContent" in the js.map files